# Как найти ядра в отношении многие-ко-многим?

Tags: графы, алгоритм, матрицы, комбинаторика

Есть два класса с отношением многие-ко-многим: напр. юзеры (U) и сообщества (C), в которых они состоят. Один юзер может состоять в нескольких сообществах, и в сообществе может быть несколько юзеров.

Мы знаем, кто в каком состоит. Можно представить данные в любом удобном виде. Пока остановился на таком:

```
c1: [u1, u2, u3],
c2: [u1, u2, u4],
c3: [u2, u3, u5, u6],
...
```

«Ядрами» называю отношения с, как минимум, двумя участниками с каждой стороны. В этом примере – два «ядра»:

```
[u1, u2] => [c1, c2],
[u2, u3] => [c1, c3],
```

**Как найти все ядра среди довольно крупных данных?**

Кроме перебора всех возможных комбинаций пока ничего не пришло в голову. Очень неэффективно на больших наборах (десятки тысяч с каждой стороны).

**Upd.** узнал про термин из теории графов – «**клика**». Похоже на то, что мне нужно, но стоит ли смешивать в граф узлы принципиально разных двух классов? И среди алгоритмов поиска клик пока не нашёл оптимальных – всё рекурсия да переборы.

[image: данные примера в виде графа]

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, надо найти, какие пользователи имеют общие интересы, т.е. состоят в одних и тех же сообществах. Если достаточно лишь того, что пользователи состоят в двух одинаковых сообществах, то можно так: перебираем все возможные сочетания двух групп, ищем пересечение множеств их пользователей. На C# это почти слово-в-слово так и записывается:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HashSet<int>[] groups = new HashSet<int>[3];
        groups[0] = new HashSet<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3});
        groups[1] = new HashSet<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 4 });
        groups[2] = new HashSet<int>(new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 6 });
        for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < groups.Length; j++)
            {
                int[] common = groups[i].Intersect(groups[j]).ToArray();
                if (common.Length >= 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Common users of groups {0} and {1}:", i, j);
                    foreach (int user in common)
                    {
                        Console.Write(user);
                        Console.Write(' ');
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, почти так, за исключением того, что каждое такое подмножество ещё имеет "вес", зависящий от числа (юзеров * 2 + сообществ) в нём, и интересуют, в первую очередь, самые «тяжёлые» подмножества. Минимумы по 2x2 – чаще всего ненужный шум.

Я сейчас примерно так и делаю. Но этот перебор `Группы x Группы x Юзеры` немного «перебор» : ) И я надеялся, что есть какая-то математика, чтобы отчасти его сократить.

Comment: Перебирать в любом случае придется. Вопрос лишь в том, чтобы перебирать то, что надо и как можно более эффективно. У меня есть парочка идей. Одна из них - перебирать, начиная с самых больших сообществ, так больше шанс, что найдем много ядер. А при достижении какого-то предела останавливаемся (дальше, скорее всего, только шум).