# Как найти клики / одинаковые комбинации в битовом массиве?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика

В массив у каждого элемента `u1..uN` есть своя комбинация битовых свойств `b1..bN`.

Задача найти наиболее крупные группы с одинаковыми включенными битами. Например:

[image: пример данных и искомых подгрупп]

Зеленым отмечены «включённые» биты, и ниже – две найденные группы. Чем-то задача похожа на поиск клик в графе, но вроде бы, задача с графом сложнее. Первый найденный кластер: строки u1 и u2 обе содержат включенными биты 1,3,4,5. Второй кластер: строки 2,3,4 одинаково содержат включенными биты 2 и 4.

В моей задаче число строк измеряется миллионами, а свойств (бит) – сотнями. Поэтому надеюсь, что есть какое-то более эффективное решение, чем перебор всех возможных комбинаций.

Находить собираюсь наиболее крупные «компании», ограничив поиск неким порогом. Бизнес цель – анализ данных пользователей в соц. сетях для выявления значимых «общностей».

Подскажите, какая здесь математика поможет?

[Связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/410194/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC), задавал раньше.

Comment: А как вы определяете группу? У вас в u2 больше включённых битов, чем в u1, так можно?

Comment: @VladD ищу группы строк, у которых присутствует одинаковая комбинация включённых битов. 1-й кластер – `u1, u2` – по общности битов `1,3,4,5`. Второй `u2,u3,u4` – по комбинации `b2, b4`.

Можно ввести «вес» группы: `кол-во строк * кол-во совпадающих битов`, или дать кол-ву строк приоритет, возведя в степень N.

Comment: Ограничения на n и m?

Comment: @Qwertiy в кластере не менее 2 строк и не менее 2 свойств. Наиболее интересны самые крупные из доступных.

Comment: Я про подсчёт по маске-ключу думал, соответственно надо не более 16-20 чтобы были для этого метода. Годится?

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет: я ожидаю более крупные кластеры. А про размерность исходных данных в 3E5 строк * 3E2 столбцов я писал в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поменять строки (а потом - столбцы) так, чтобы включённые биты максимально приблизились к левому углу.
Это приводит задачу к каноническому виду, поскольку значительное количество разных массивов сводятся к одному. В размерностях приведённого примера выигрыш по количеству масок **в 4!*5! = 2880 раз**, в то время как затраты на перестановку столбцов и строк по данным сортировки эквивалентны обработке **~+10 масок**

P.S. К полученному массиву можно применить алгоритм [Кадане 2D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475362/2d-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5/475515#475515), который можно усложнить вычёркиванием одной-двух строк (столбцов), в зависимости от размерности массива.

Comment: Это оптимизация. На большом массиве такая сортировка во-первых может оказаться ресурсоёмкой, а во-вторых, на «равномерно распредлеённых данных, ни к чему не приведёт, т.к. «центр тяжести» включённых битов, по теор.вероятности, всегда окажется примерно в центре. Т.е. перемещая вкл. биты одной строки влево, мы тем самым для другой их отдалим вправо.

Comment: @Sergiks По теории вероятностей, существует корреляция между центром тяжести фигуры и центром тяжести маски. В приведённом примере первый кластер соответствует максимально заполненным строкам, а второй - максимально заполненным столбцам. Таким образом, перестановка повышает (условную) вероятность угадывания правильной маски.