# 2D Алгоритм Кадане

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Понадобилось свести задачу к алгоритму Кадане для двумерного массива. Нашел несколько реализаций этого алгоритма, но все они непонятны и используют другой подход для нахождения частичных сумм. Поэтому я стал писать сам. Подскажите, что я делаю не так? На этих входных данных должно получиться 15.

Ищем максимальную сумму. Идею я описал на идеоне.

https://ideone.com/Ov6040

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    int n, p;
    int sum = 0, max_sum = 0;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > m;

    std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin >> n;
    // Устанавливаем размеры матрицы, которая хранит суммы
    m.resize(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        m[i].resize(n);

    // Если индексы указывают на первую ячейку строки, то просто копируем в нее введенное число
    // В противном случае копируем в нее сумму числа из предыдущей ячейки и введенного
    // Таким образом, i-я ячейка строки хранит сумму первых i чисел
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            std::cin >> p;
            if(j) m[i][j] = m[i][j - 1] + p;
            else  m[i][j] = p;
        }

    for(int left = 0; left < n; left++) // Фиксируем левый столбец искомой матрицы
        for(int right = left; right < n; right++){  // Двигаем правый столбец искомой матрицы вправо
            sum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){ // Цикл для суммирования по столбцу
                if(right == 0)
                    sum += m[j][right]; // Суммируем элементы первого столбца
                else
                    sum += m[j][right] - m[j][left - 1];
                if(sum < 0) sum = 0;
                max_sum = std::max(sum, max_sum);
            }
        }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            std::cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << max_sum << std::endl;

    std::cin >> p;
```

}

ПС. Обнуление `sum` я несколько раз переписывал, и всегда получалось неправильно.

Comment: А отладчик что показывает?

Comment: Отладчик не поможет. Что мне в нем искать? Похоже, я не все учел в реализации. Здесь максимальаня матрица будет { {9, 2}, {-4, 1}, {-1, 8} }. То есть надо как-то проигнорировать {0, -2}. Похоже, я как-то неправильно это реализовал.

Comment: Если вы можете реализовать алгоритм в голове, вы сможете сравнить все этапы вычислений в машине с заведомо корректным алгоритмом. При помощи отладчика, он для этого и нужен.

Comment: Я могу реализовать его в голове только частично. Я не понимаю, при каких условиях надо обнулять сумму. Говорят, что при условии, что она стала отрицательна. Но это не работает.

Comment: Не вижу исходных данных - ни здесь, ни на идеоне

Comment: Входные данные на идеоне в инпуте: в первой строке размерность квадратной матрицы, в остальных строках сама матрица.

Comment: Готово! А обнуления сумм остались внутри одномерного алгоритма.

Comment: Исправил. Двумерные массивы надёжней.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идеи [линейного алгоритма](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/13713) проще, а реализация - быстрее:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    max_ending_here += Number[i];
        if(max_ending_here > max_so_far)max_so_far = max_ending_here;
        if(max_ending_here < 0)max_ending_here = 0;
}
```

Программа на PHP (с указанием положения последовательности):

```
$n = array(34, -41, 59, 26, -53, 58, 97, -93, -23, 84);

$start = -1;    // начальный индекс
$finish = -1;   // конечный индекс
$msf = 0;       // максимальная сумма для групп с начальным индексом $start
$meh = 0;       // максимальная сумма для групп с конечным индексом $finish

$len = count($n);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
    if($meh==0) $start=$i;
    $meh = $meh + $n[$i];
    if($meh>$msf){
        $finish = $i;
        $msf = $meh;        
    }
    $meh = max($meh,0);
    printf("<br>N[$i] = %d &emsp; msf = $msf &emsp; mex = $meh &emsp; start = $start &emsp; finish = $finish", $n[$i]); 
}
printf("<br><br>Алгоритм Кадане: сумма N[$start:$finish] = %d", $msf);
```

Результаты:

```
N[0] = 34   msf = 34   mex = 34   start = 0   finish = 0
N[1] = -41   msf = 34   mex = 0   start = 0   finish = 0
N[2] = 59   msf = 59   mex = 59   start = 2   finish = 2
N[3] = 26   msf = 85   mex = 85   start = 2   finish = 3
N[4] = -53   msf = 85   mex = 32   start = 2   finish = 3
N[5] = 58   msf = 90   mex = 90   start = 2   finish = 5
N[6] = 97   msf = 187   mex = 187   start = 2   finish = 6
N[7] = -93   msf = 187   mex = 94   start = 2   finish = 6
N[8] = -23   msf = 187   mex = 71   start = 2   finish = 6
N[9] = 84   msf = 187   mex = 155   start = 2   finish = 6

Алгоритм Кадане: сумма N[2:6] = 187
```

Таблица ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yxbGiDVE8JoKZgIxOPj_D0RtBuC1phBWZ6R3VpWgauQ/edit#gid=0)):
[image: Kadane2]

P.S. Полученную одномерную функцию можно без изменений применить и в 2D алгоритме. А подавая на вход суммы элементов из 1,2,3,4 соседних строк, удаётся решить задачу полностью.

2D - программа имеет вид:

```
$n = array(
    array( 0, 2,-7, 0),
    array( 9, 2,-6, 2),
    array(-4, 1,-4, 1),
    array(-1, 8, 0, -2),
);

function kadane_1d($n) {    // на входе 1D массив, на выходе - сумма
    $start = -1;    // начальный индекс
    $finish = -1;   // конечный индекс
    $msf = 0;       // максимальная сумма для групп с начальным индексом $start
    $meh = 0;       // максимальная сумма для групп с конечным индексом $finish
    $len = count($n);
    for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++){
        $meh = $meh + $n[$i];
        if($meh>$msf){
            $msf = $meh;        
        }
        $meh = max($meh,0);
        printf(" %d&emsp;", $n[$i]); 
    }
    printf("Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = %d<br>", $msf);
    return $msf; 
}

$rows = count($n);
$cols = count($n[0]);   
$sums = array();
$max = 0;

for($h=0; $h<$rows; $h++){                      // цикл по высоте матриц
    printf("<br>Строк в подматрицах: %d<br>", $h+1);
    for ($i=0; $i<$rows-$h; $i++) {
        if($h==0){
            $sums[$i] = $n[$i];
        }else{
            for($j=0; $j<$cols-1; $j++)             // пересчёт сумм
                $sums[$i][$j] += $n[$h+$i][$j]; 
        }
        $k = kadane_1d($sums[$i]);
        $max = ($k>$max) ? $k : $max;
    }
}
print("<br>Максимальная сумма равна: $max")
```

Результат:

```
Строк в подматрицах: 1
0  2  -7  0 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 2
9  2  -6  2 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 11
-4  1  -4  1 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 1
-1  8  0  -2 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 8

Строк в подматрицах: 2
9  4  -13  0 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 13
5  3  -10  2 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 8
-5  9  -4  1 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 9

Строк в подматрицах: 3
5  5  -17  0 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 10
4  11  -10  2 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 15

Строк в подматрицах: 4
4  13  -17  0 Алгоритм Кадане 1D: сумма N = 17

Максимальная сумма равна: 17
```